# how to import Kmedoids in pycharm?

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to use KMedoids. I install sklearn_extra in jupyter and then use this code:

```
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
```

It works correctly.

But in pycharm I could not use this code. because there isn't sklearn_extra modul.
so use `pip insatll sklearn_extra` and `pip install sikit-learn-extra` but it doesn't work in pycharm. I tried other code for installation but it didn't solve.
what is your solution???

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Scikit-learn-extra in pycharm interpreter by going into settings, then the code for K-medoid will work.